Set-builder notation form
I have a set A = {3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 38, ...} and I need to write it using the set-builder notation. We can see that each number in the set can be obtained by adding odd natural numbers to the previous one, starting from 2. For example, 11 is given by
2 + 2*0+1 + 2*1+1 + 2*2+1. This may be generalized as $n = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k + 1)$. So in set-builder notation this would be in the form
$$A = \{n : n = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k + 1),\ k \in \mathbb{Z},\ k \geq 0 \}$$
It is probably a silly question, but is this correct? In any case, is there a cleaner way to write it without using the summation operator?

This is a good start—let's improve it! First note that some of the symbols are extraneous: the way the sum is indexed already implies that $k$ will take only nonnegative integer values. So we can simplify to
$$
A = \biggl\{n \colon n = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2k + 1) \biggr\}.
$$
However, we don't really mean a single infinite series—we mean a succession of finite series of the same form. So we can correct to
$$
A = \biggl\{n \colon n = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^K (2k + 1), \, K\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\} \biggr\}.
$$
The variable $n$ can be eliminated from the notation—complicated expressions are allowed to go on the left side of the set-builder notation—giving
$$
A = \biggl\{2 + \sum_{k=0}^K (2k + 1) \colon K\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\} \biggr\}.
$$
This is how I would write it, other than replacing $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ with a symbol you might have for it ($\Bbb N_0$ or $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$, depending on your definitions.)
As an added bonus, it's a great exercise to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^K (2k + 1) = (K+1)^2$ exactly! So we can simplify the set notation even further to
$$
A = \{ 2+L^2 \colon L\in\Bbb N \}
$$
(assuming $\Bbb N$ starts at $1$ for us). But that's a separate issue from working on the set-builder notation itself.

Thank you so much for the comprehensive clarification and the alternative you proposed. I really appreciate it!
